# Show that $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\ge2\sqrt n$

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\ge2\sqrt n$ where $G'$ is the complement of some graph $G$ of order $n$.

I've so far managed to show $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\le n+1$ (probably not too useful) and that $\chi(G)\chi(G')\ge n$. I hoped that I could somehow fiddle these round to get what I wanted but haven't managed it yet. Any pointers on where to go next would be useful, or if I need to use a different approach.

Comment: What is $\chi$? Also, whatever it is, if it is always nonnegative, then the result easily follows from the AM-GM inequality: $\frac{\chi(G) + \chi(G')}{2} \geq \sqrt{\chi(G)\chi(G')}$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\geq 2\sqrt{n}$.

Proof: Since both $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(G')$ are at least one we know that $(\chi(G)-\chi(G'))^2\geq 0$ and so $\chi(G)^2-2\chi(G)\cdot \chi(G')+\chi(G')^2\geq 0$. Adding $4\chi(G)\cdot \chi(G')$ to both sides of the equation we obtain $\chi(G)^2+2\chi(G)\cdot\chi(G')+\chi(G')^2\geq 4\chi(G)\cdot\chi(G')$ and factoring the left-hand side we now have $(\chi(G)+\chi(G'))^2\geq 4\chi(G)\cdot\chi(G')$. Taking the square root of both sides gives us $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\geq 2\sqrt{\chi(G)\cdot \chi(G')}$ and since you know that $\chi(G)\cdot \chi(G')\geq n$ we can conclude that $\chi(G)+\chi(G')\geq 2\sqrt{n}$.